# Need to add a surrounding div to fancybox or add a class to body when clicked

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to create multiple fancyboxes on the same page that when clicked open up with either a iframe in a iphone, ipad or desktop browser.

I got the image on the default overlay, but i can't add a class to it for each individual click so I can display a diff image for the iphone, ipad ect.

Here the jquery for two to work. I can add the class to the fancybox_wrap, but i need to target the overlay above this which handles the background.

```
$(".fancybox-420").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 480,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    minWidth    : 420,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '90%',
    height      : '90%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    padding     : 0,
    tpl: {
              wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap iphone_420" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
              next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
              prev: '<a title="Prev" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
    }
}); 

$(".fancybox-300").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 320,
    maxHeight   : 569,
    minWidth    : 300,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '90%',
    height      : '90%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    padding     : 0,
    tpl: {
              wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap iphone_300" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
              next: '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next"><span></span></a>',
              prev: '<a title="Prev" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev"><span></span></a>'
    }
});
```

I thought i would be able to add a script when clicked on, it would add a specific class to the body so i could target the fancybox_overlay layer for each diff iframe, but it breaks the fancybox script it doesnt pop up

```
    $(".fancybox-300").on('click', function( e ){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".fancybox-overlay").addClass("iphone300");
});
$(document).on('click', function( e ){
    if(e.target.className!="fancybox-300")
    $(".fancybox-overlay").removeClass("iphone300");
});
```

I cant find anything similar to what i am after.

I pretty much need to be able to add a unique class for each fancybox iframe that when clicked I can change the background for each.

e.g .iphone .fancybox_overlay , .ipad .fancybox_overlay

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind all your fancyboxes to the same selector so you won't need to have a different script for each fancybox. You can add an extra class to your links to separate each fancybox like

```
<a class="fancybox i300"...>..</a>
<a class="fancybox i420"...>...</a>
```

Then you can declare different API options of each fancybox in separated variables like :

```
// settings for fancybox 300
var f300 = {
    maxWidth: 320,
    maxHeight: 569,
    minWidth: 300
};
// settings for fancybox 420
var f420 = {
    maxWidth: 480,
    maxHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 420
};
```

...and use a single script with the common shared options AND using the `afterLoad` callback to apply each individual setting, depending on the *class* as well as adding the corresponding class to the fancybox overlay like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // common API options
    fitToView: false,
    width: '90%',
    height: '90%',
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    padding: 0,
    afterLoad: function () {
        if ($(this.element).hasClass("i300")) {
            $.extend(this, f300);
            $(".fancybox-overlay").addClass("iphone_300");
        } else if ($(this.element).hasClass("i420")) {
            $.extend(this, f420);
            $(".fancybox-overlay").addClass("iphone_420");
        }
    }
});
```

**Notice** we are adding classes either `iphone_300` or `iphone_420` to the fancybox overlay, which may have different styles within your own css stylesheet like

```
.iphone_300 {
    background: rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.8)
}
.iphone_420 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C9sTg/)</kbd>

---

**EDIT** :

> when i put these in a ***rel=gallery***, that when i click next it doesnt remove the previous addclass

Just add this as first line inside the `afterLoad` callback :

```
$(".fancybox-overlay").removeClass("iphone_300").removeClass("iphone_420");
```

See updated <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8sCtM/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks was exactly what i was after. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: just noticed that when i put these in a rel=gallery, that when i click next it doesnt remove the previous addclass from one iframe to the next. So its breaking the backgrounds i have set.